# Frame Comes up BLANK when running application (JAVA)

Tags: java, swing, joptionpane

So, with the help of some guys here, I was able to get this code to compile and run. But now, another problem has presented itself. When running the application, the panel is blank. I'm a newb, and i know i'm doing something stupid. I've been sitting here all night trying to get this to fully work, but can't figure out what else I need to do to get it to work.

```
 import java.awt.*;
import java.applet.*;
import java.awt.event.*;
import java.awt.Graphics;
import javax.swing.JOptionPane;
import javax.swing.JApplet;
import java.awt.event.*;

public class telephoneKeypad extends javax.swing.JFrame
{


    public void telephoneKeypad()
    {
        Panel pnlKeyPad = new Panel();
          GridLayout gridLayout1 = new GridLayout();
          Button btnZero = new Button();
          Button btnOne = new Button();
          Button btnTwo = new Button();
          Button btnThree = new Button();
        Button btnFour = new Button();
          Button btnFive = new Button();
          Button btnSix = new Button();
          Button btnSeven = new Button();
          Button btnEight = new Button();
          Button btnNine = new Button();
          Button btnStar = new Button();
          Button btnHash = new Button();

        TextField tfNumber = new TextField();
          Button btnDial = new Button();
          BorderLayout borderLayout1 = new BorderLayout();
          Panel pnlNumberEntry = new Panel();
          FlowLayout flowLayout1 = new FlowLayout();





            btnOne.setLabel("1");
            btnTwo.setLabel("2");
            btnThree.setLabel("3");
            btnFour.setLabel("4");
            btnFive.setLabel("5");
            btnSix.setLabel("6");
            btnSeven.setLabel("7");
            btnEight.setLabel("8");
            btnNine.setLabel("9");
            btnStar.setLabel("*");
            btnZero.setLabel("0");
            btnHash.setLabel("#");
            btnDial.setLabel("Dial");

            pnlNumberEntry.setLayout(flowLayout1);
            pnlKeyPad.setLayout(gridLayout1);
            this.setLayout(borderLayout1);
            this.add(pnlNumberEntry, BorderLayout.NORTH);
            pnlNumberEntry.add(tfNumber, null);
            pnlNumberEntry.add(btnDial, null);
            this.add(pnlKeyPad, BorderLayout.CENTER);
            pnlKeyPad.add(btnOne, null);
            pnlKeyPad.add(btnTwo, null);
            pnlKeyPad.add(btnThree, null);
            pnlKeyPad.add(btnFour, null);
            pnlKeyPad.add(btnFive, null);
            pnlKeyPad.add(btnSix, null);
            pnlKeyPad.add(btnSeven, null);
            pnlKeyPad.add(btnEight, null);
            pnlKeyPad.add(btnNine, null);
            pnlKeyPad.add(btnStar, null);
            pnlKeyPad.add(btnZero, null);
            pnlKeyPad.add(btnHash, null);
        }

            public static void main(String args[])
                {
                telephoneKeypad kpad = new telephoneKeypad();
                kpad.setBounds(500, 500, 500, 500);
                kpad.setVisible(true);
    }
 }
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You declared the constructor wrong - `public void telephoneKeypad()` instead of `public telephoneKeypad()`

You would still have to work on the panels, but this will actually run your constructor and not the default constructor.

Also, usually class name start with Uppercase letter.

Comment: Thanks, I don't know how I forgot to remove 'void' from that. Now All I have to do is change the size of these panels and i'm set!

Comment: @Josh  Given you seem to have ignore *every* piece of [advice I offered](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5617955/keypad-java-application-compiles-but-doesnt-show-anything/5618896#5618896) on your last thread, I'd say you are very far from 'set'.  But if you ignore me, I see no point even trying to help.  :(